# Resultset doesn't get the value from PreparedStatement with one variable?

Tags: java, sql, db2, prepared-statement, resultset

I'm currently having a problem with my PreparedStatement for my SQL Query.
I'm trying to make a program where a user can search the database with 1 or optionally 2 variables. The latter part, searching with 2 variables works with no problem. However when trying to use just one variable entered by the user my Resultset doesn't seem to get a value from the PreparedStatement (which I checked in the debugger and confirmed that it get's a value). Now I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, especially since it seemed to work before with 2 variables.

My relevant code:

```
public class BTRDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements BTRDao {

static Connection dbConnection = null;
public static PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

public static void sqlquery() {
    try {

        String btrname = View.searchbtrname.getText();
        String btrplz = View.searchbtrplz.getText();

        if (btrplz.isEmpty()) {
            String btrResult = "SELECT * FROM BP.TBBBST WHERE BBSTNABEG = TRIM(UPPER(?))";

            dbConnection = AbstractDao.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(btrResult);
            preparedStatement.setObject(1, btrname);

            Model.search();
        } else {
            String btrResult = "SELECT * FROM BP.TBBBST WHERE BBSTNABEG = TRIM(UPPER(?)) AND BBSTPLZ = TRIM(UPPER(?))";

            dbConnection = AbstractDao.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(btrResult);
            preparedStatement.setObject(1, btrname);
            preparedStatement.setObject(2, btrplz);

            Model.search();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println("A SQL error occured: ");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        System.out.println("An error occured: ");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Collection<BTRBean> getBTR() throws SQLException,
        IOException {
    final Collection<BTRBean> result = new ArrayList<BTRBean>();

    ResultSet resultset = null;
    try {
        resultset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        // while loop for returning all found data
        while (resultset.next()) {
            BTRBean btr = new BTRBean();
            int btrid = resultset.getInt(1);
            String btrplz = resultset.getString(2);
            String btrname = resultset.getString(4);
            result.add(btr);
            System.out.println("BTR-ID: " + btrid + " BTR PLZ: " + btrplz + " BTR: " + btrname);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("There was an error with SQL processing: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        System.out.println("NullPointerException: ");
        npe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        closeConnection(resultset);

    }

    return result;
}

}
```

The search method inside my Model class:

```
public static void search() throws SQLException, IOException {
    try {
        BTRDaoImpl btr1 = new BTRDaoImpl();
        btr1.getBTR();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception (btr1)");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception (btr1)");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have in Model.search(); ?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, overlooked that. Added it now.

Comment: Does your class BTRDaoImpl have a constructor ?

Comment: No it doesn't. It simply consists of my sqlquery method which is being called in my controller on a button click and the following CollectionBean.